# ModelVisual3D not rendering properly in DockPanel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, modelvisual3d

I am extremely new to WPF and am trying to create an application where I will have a globe plotted in one tab with a flat map in the second tab. I was able to get the globe plotted in a test application, with the code below:

```
    <Window x:Class="SphereTutorial.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SphereTutorial"
        xmlns:earth="clr-namespace:SphereTutorial.Globe"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.Resources>
            <earth:SphereMeshGenerator x:Key="SphereGeometrySource1"/>
            <MeshGeometry3D x:Key="SphereGeometry1" 

                            Positions="{Binding Source={StaticResource 
                                  SphereGeometrySource1}, Path=Geometry.Positions}"

                            TriangleIndices="{Binding Source={StaticResource 
                                  SphereGeometrySource1}, Path=Geometry.TriangleIndices}"

                            TextureCoordinates="{Binding Source={StaticResource SphereGeometrySource1}, Path=Geometry.TextureCoordinates}"/>

        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.Background>
            Black
        </Grid.Background>
        <Viewport3D x:Name="mainScene3D">
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="mainCam" LookDirection="-1,0,0" Position="5,0,0" UpDirection="0,1,0"/>
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <Model3DGroup>
                        <AmbientLight Color="White"/>
                        <GeometryModel3D Geometry="{StaticResource SphereGeometry1}">
                            <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                <MaterialGroup>
                                    <DiffuseMaterial>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="H:\C#\SphereTutorial\SphereTutorial\Images\Earth.jpg"/>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                    </DiffuseMaterial>
                                </MaterialGroup>
                            </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                        </GeometryModel3D>
                    </Model3DGroup>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
        </Viewport3D>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The sphere code I pulled from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292873/wpf-3d-rotating-sphere-gui) with the code given here:

```
    namespace VenProp.Sphere3D
{
    class SphereMeshGenerator
    {
        private int _slices = 100;
        private int _stacks = 50;
        private Point3D _center = new Point3D();
        private double _radius = 1;

        public int Slices
        {
            get { return _slices; }
            set { _slices = value; }
        }

        public int Stacks
        {
            get { return _stacks; }
            set { _stacks = value; }
        }

        public Point3D Center
        {
            get { return _center; }
            set { _center = value; }
        }

        public double Radius
        {
            get { return _radius; }
            set { _radius = value; }
        }

        public MeshGeometry3D Geometry
        {
            get
            {
                return CalculateMesh();
            }
        }


        private MeshGeometry3D CalculateMesh()
        {
            MeshGeometry3D mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();

            for (int stack = 0; stack <= Stacks; stack++)
            {
                double phi = Math.PI / 2 - stack * Math.PI / Stacks; 
                double y = _radius * Math.Sin(phi);
                double scale = -_radius * Math.Cos(phi);

                for (int slice = 0; slice <= Slices; slice++)
                {
                    double theta = slice * 2 * Math.PI / Slices; 
                    double x = scale * Math.Sin(theta); 
                    double z = scale * Math.Cos(theta); 

                    Vector3D normal = new Vector3D(x, y, z);  
                    mesh.Normals.Add(normal);
                    mesh.Positions.Add(normal + Center);  
                    mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point((double)slice / Slices, (double)stack / Stacks));
                }
            }

            for (int stack = 0; stack <= Stacks; stack++)
            {
                int top = (stack + 0) * (Slices + 1);
                int bot = (stack + 1) * (Slices + 1);

                for (int slice = 0; slice < Slices; slice++)
                {
                    if (stack != 0)
                    {
                        mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(top + slice);
                        mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(bot + slice);
                        mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(top + slice + 1);
                    }

                    if (stack != Stacks - 1)
                    {
                        mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(top + slice + 1);
                        mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(bot + slice);
                        mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(bot + slice + 1);
                    }
                }
            }

            return mesh;
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to verify that it does work with this method; however, when I went to implement the same logic in my application, things broke down. For some reason, it starts to render the image on the edges only. I have a feeling that it could have to do with being in a DockPanel? The 2D image works fine in its DockPanel though. Here is the code that does not work:

```
<Window x:Class="VenProp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VenProp"
        xmlns:sphere="clr-namespace:VenProp.Sphere3D"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="VenProp"
        Height="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}, Converter={local:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.9' }" 
        Width="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}, Converter={local:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.9' }"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Background="#FFE4E4E4">

    <!-- Window Resources -->
    <Window.Resources>
        <sphere:SphereMeshGenerator x:Key="SphereGeometrySource"/>
        <MeshGeometry3D x:Key="SphereGeometry"
                        Positions="{Binding Source={StaticResource SphereGeometrySource}, Path=Geometry.Positions}"
                        TriangleIndices="{Binding Source={StaticResource SphereGeometrySource}, Path=Geometry.TriangleIndicies}"
                        TextureCoordinates="{Binding Source={StaticResource SphereGeometrySource}, Path=Geometry.TextureCoordinates}"/>

    </Window.Resources>


    <!-- Overall Container is VERTICAL-->
    <DockPanel>

        <!-- Top Menu -->
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="Black">
            <MenuItem Header="_File"></MenuItem>
        </Menu>

        <!-- Main toolbar -->
        <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Button>
                <!-- Put image here-->
            </Button>
            <Button Content="Button2"/>
        </ToolBar>

        <!-- StatusBar -->
        <StatusBar x:Name="statusBar" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"  />

        <!-- Inner container is horizontal -->
        <DockPanel>

            <Separator Width="2" Foreground="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}"/>
            <!-- Throw Tree into a dock panel with its label-->
            <StackPanel Width="310" DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,2" Background="#FFE4E4E4">
                <Label Content="Object Browser" FontSize="12" Background="LightGray"/>
                <TreeView x:Name="ObjectBrowser" BorderThickness="2" Height="620" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                    <TreeView.BitmapEffect>
                        <BevelBitmapEffect BevelWidth="5" Relief="0.4" LightAngle="320"/>
                    </TreeView.BitmapEffect>
                </TreeView>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>

        <Separator Width="10" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.45,0.541" />
        <!-- Tabs for graphics windows -->
        <TabControl x:Name="tabGraphics" BorderThickness="5">
            <TabControl.BitmapEffect>
                <BevelBitmapEffect BevelWidth="15" Relief="0.4"/>
            </TabControl.BitmapEffect>

            <!-- 3D Earth Model -->
            <TabItem x:Name="graphics3D" Header="3D Graphics">
                <DockPanel Background="Black">
                    <Viewport3D x:Name="mainScene3D">
                        <!--Camera-->
                        <Viewport3D.Camera>
                            <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="mainCam" LookDirection="-1,0,0" Position="5,0,0" UpDirection="0,1,0"/>
                        </Viewport3D.Camera>

                        <!--Earth Model-->
                        <ModelVisual3D>
                            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                                <Model3DGroup>
                                    <AmbientLight Color="White"/>
                                    <GeometryModel3D Geometry="{StaticResource SphereGeometry}">
                                        <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                            <MaterialGroup>
                                                <DiffuseMaterial>
                                                    <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="H:\C#\VenProp\VenProp\Images\Earth.jpg"/>
                                                    </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                </DiffuseMaterial>
                                            </MaterialGroup>
                                        </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                    </GeometryModel3D>
                                </Model3DGroup>
                            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                        </ModelVisual3D>
                    </Viewport3D>
                </DockPanel>
            </TabItem>


            <TabItem x:Name="graphics2D" Header="2D Graphics">
                <DockPanel Background="Gray">
                    <Image Source="H:\C#\VenProp\VenProp\Images/Earth.jpg"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

For testing purposes, if you replace the ImageBrush with, say a SolidColorBrush, the same effect will happen.

Does anybody have any idea what is going on? Also, I am new to Stack Overflow, so if there is anything I can do to make my question more clear, please let me know. Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always check your **Output** window for binding errors, like this:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: **'TriangleIndicies'** property not found on 'object' ''MeshGeometry3D' (HashCode=33785274)'. BindingExpression:Path=Geometry.TriangleIndicies; DataItem='SphereMeshGenerator' (HashCode=18281552); target element is 'MeshGeometry3D' (HashCode=34085817); target property is 'TriangleIndices' (type 'Int32Collection')

After changing from ***TriangleIndicies*** to ***TriangleIndices***, it worked just fine:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something dumb.

Comment: I did Vote up, however, since I had less than 15 rep it said it would count, but not show up. Just did it again now that I have more than 15. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @MikeC : Thank You !